# SOAP response returning ArrayList

Tags: java, web-services, soap, arraylist

I wrote a very simple webservice which returns a ArrayList. when I try to test my web service using SOAPUI , the response is empty. I am deploying this application in Tomcat.

Here is my code:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.enterprise.ws.WebServiceInterface")
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebServiceInterface{

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> listSample() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("1212");
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Interface :

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface WebServiceInterface {

    @WebMethod
    ArrayList<String> listSample();

}
```

Here is my SOAPUI response .

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any other ways to be sure that your service is working as desired before saying that result is not as per the expectations?

Comment: yes, I have. I have implemented 3 other methods to see if there was an error with the service, The 3 other methods which returns a normal String works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by this *JAX-B* bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-223

The problem is that if you use a *JAX-WS 2.0/JAX-B 2.0* you can not use a collection class directly as a return type for a `@WebMethod`.

There are two possibles workarounds to avoid this issue:

One is to use an `Array` instead of `ArrayList` avoiding the use of collection class:

**Interface**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface WebServiceInterface {

    @WebMethod
    String[] listSample();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.enterprise.ws.WebServiceInterface")
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebServiceInterface{

    @Override
    public String[] listSample() {
        return new String[]{"1212"};
    }
}
```

Another possible workaround is to create a *POJO* to wrap your `ArrayList`, and on the `@WebMethod` return the *POJO* type instead:

**POJO class**

```
public class PojoSample {

     private List<String> listSample;
     // create getters and setters
     ...
}
```

**POJO Interface**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface WebServiceInterface {

    @WebMethod
    PojoSample listSample();
}
```

**POJO Implementation**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.enterprise.ws.WebServiceInterface")
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebServiceInterface{

    @Override
    public PojoSample listSample() {
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("1212");

        PojoSample pojo = new PojoSample();
        pojo.setListSample(arrayList);
        return pojo;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I Solved that just using the code below

```
 @WebMethod(operationName = "listarPersonas")
public List<Persona> listarPersonas() {

    return PersonaService.PERSONAS_REGISTRADAS;
}
```

Just replace List instead Arraylist.

regards;

Answer (score 0):

Try soap binding document with wrapped parameter style insted of RPC binding.

`@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT,use=Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)`

With this you can write web method with List return value, or parameter as a List:

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "returnName")
public List<MyBean> methodName(@WebParam(name = "paramName") List<ParamBean> paramList);
```